# subreport could not shown error

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, subreport

I'm creating a main report with a subreport for Glossary only. Is there a way I can just show the Glossary as a subreport without passing a parameter value? My report is running fine when previewed in visual studio 2015 but when deployed to SSRS 2014, the subreport then comes up with an error- Subreport could not be shown. Would appreciate any help or advice I can get.

Many thanks

Comment: In order for the subreport to run without parameters when called from another report, is to set default values for all the parameters on the subreport

Comment: Thank so much for the help niktrs.

Comment: You are welcome